# Arduino Mega driving 5V to 12 V

Tags: arduino, voltage, mosfet, atmega

I am working on a project which involves using an Arduino Mega, and I am trying to use an NMOSFET (BUZ101S) and an NPN BJT (2N3904) to drive the 5V output from the MCU back and forth between 0V and 12V across "SOL".

At the moment, the problem I have is that Vgs always stays high, thus driving SOL on all the time, and I cant figure out why this occurs.

Here is my circuit diagram:

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Look at this http://www.sampson-jeff.com/tcrobowar/motor1/ver1.htm

Comment: There is a connection after 300ohm resistor. What it does?

Comment: Shouldn't there be p-MOSFET?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but need to modify your circuit. A N channel MOSFET requires a positive \$V_{gs}\$ to turn on. If the solenoid is always on in your current circuit, you have drain and source reversed, and starting over with a fresh MOSFET would be a good idea. This configuration should get you going, but may need to play with some resistor values.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fThTM5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>